# How do I setup the clock form pwm device tree overlay

Tags: pwm, raspbian-buster, compute-module-3

I am trying to use pwm on GPIO pin 40 but I have been unsuccessful so far.
I am using `pwm` as device tree overlay in my config.txt
`dtoverlay=pwm,pin=40`

After that I tried performing the below actions

`root@rpi3:/sys/class/pwm/pwmchip0# echo 0 > export`

`root@rpi3:/sys/class/pwm/pwmchip0# echo 1000000 > pwm0/period`

`root@rpi3:/sys/class/pwm/pwmchip0# echo 500000 > pwm0/duty_cycle`

`root@rpi3:/sys/class/pwm/pwmchip0# echo 1 > pwm0/enable`

I tried doing the same thing on channel 1 but still nothing.
(I have an Oscilloscope connected to the pwm line)

I added `dtoverlay=pwm,pin=40,clock=1000000` and turned my audio off in config.txt

But I am still unable to see a pwm pulse. Why is that? The Documentation, states me to setup the clock before using it. So How do I setup my clock?
Also Software PWM works via python code works. But that is not somethings that I want. Since that requires me to run a python script on an infinite loop.

Comment: Are you sure your clock settings and dutycycle are acceptable to that dtoverlay?  As an aside you could use pigpio to start the PWM pulses and then exit the program - that would leave PWM running.

Comment: @joan How do I know the acceptable dutycycle and clocksettings. Right now by trial and error it won't let me go below a certain value. So Thats about it. And I haven't looked in to pigpio

Comment: @joan please add your comments as an answer. I think it is a great suggestion